# Android: Playing an audio clip onClick

Tags: android, audio

How do I set up an audiofile to play when a user touches an image.

Where should I store the audio file and what code should I use to actually play the file?
I don't want to bring up the MediaPlayer interface or anything like that.

I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
foo = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.foo);
    foo.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
if (foo.isTouched()) {

 playAudioFile();
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: As described in the answer below, put `my_sound.mp3` into `res/raw/` and then reference it via `R.raw.my_sound`. However, then you have two choices: `MediaPlayer` and `SoundPool`. For efficient memory management, you should use a library to work with those classes: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-Audio

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This won't create a bring up the MediaPlayer interface... it will just play the sound you want.

```
Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestSonido.this, R.raw.slayer);  
  mp.start();
 }
});
```

In this case, `R.raw.slayer` represents an audio file called `slayer.mp3` that is stored in the `res/raw/` folder and once you click the button the droid will rock you...

Comment: What will happen if i click button twice before completing previous audio clip , I think then it will play dual audio?

Answer (score 8):

You can also achieve the same using `SoundPool`.

`MediaPlayer` first loads the whole sound data in memory then play, so it produces some lag when we switch among sounds frequently.

`SoundPool` is a better option with small size sound file and produces better result with `.ogg` media file.

```
SoundPool pl = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        // 5 indicates the maximum number of simultaneous streams for this SoundPool object
pl.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                // The onLoadComplet method is called when a sound has completed loading.
                soundPool.play(sampleId, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1);
                // second and third parameters indicates left and right value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
            }
});

Button btn = findViewById(R.id.boton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

     int sound = pl.load(this, R.raw.sound_01, 0);

 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void aud_play(View view) {
  if (!mp.isPlaying()) {   //If media player is not playing it.

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_name);
    mp.start();      

  } else {// Toast of Already playing ...
}
}
```

Comment: I have prevented DUAL audio problem .