# unable to play sound using android MediaPlayer in dialog?

Tags: android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play sound in a dialog. But somehow, it doesnt work. I'm not sure whether it's because its in a dialog or so.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/record");
    final String soundUri = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" +childName; 
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(MLT_File.this);

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MLT_File.this, Uri.parse(soundUri));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
    LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(MLT_File.this);
    layout2.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    final ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(MLT_File.this);
    btn.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play));
    layout2.addView(btn);

    layout.addView(layout2);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mp.isPlaying())
            {
                mp.pause();
                btn.setImageDrawable(MLT_File.this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play));
            }//video is playing

            else
            {
                mp.start();
                btn.setImageDrawable(MLT_File.this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause));
            }
        }   
    });//onClickListener

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MLT_File.this);
    builder.setView(layout);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            itemClick (1,soundUri);
        }
    });//delete

    builder.setNeutralButton("Share", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            itemClick (3,soundUri);
        }
    });//share

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }           
    });//cancel
    builder.create().show();
```

There is only 1 error :

```
01-30 16:27:29.251: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(32416): setDataSource: outside path in JNI is �x@
```

I got the idea of using mediaplayer from [Android: Playing an audio clip onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041763/android-playing-an-audio-clip-onclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use,

```
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(soundUri);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

And let me know what happen..

Also look at this example [MusicDroid - Audio Player Part I](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i)

Comment: its not working. do i need to add anything in manifest to access it ?

Comment: it works.. but because i didn't set the volume, therefore i thought it does not. thanks !